# NAs introduced by coercion in mutate dplyr while using dynamic column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using dplyr mutate to compute rank difference between 2 columns. I am trying to use suffix to choose the column name instead of changing it every time.

```
suffix1 = ".day"
suffix2 = ".nit"
mergeddf <- left_join(df1, df2, by="col1", suffix = c(suffix1,suffix2)) %>% 
  select(-paste0("Description",suffix2)) %>% 
  mutate(RankDiff = as.numeric(as.character(paste0("Rank",suffix1))) - as.numeric(as.character(paste0("Rank",suffix2)))) %>% 
  arrange(RankDiff)
```

The `suffix1` and `suffix2` is perfectly added and also picked up at `select`. But in mutate, I get the following error:

> 1: Problem with `mutate()` column `RankDiff`. ℹ `RankDiff = -...`. ℹ
> NAs introduced by coercion  2: Problem with `mutate()` column
> `RankDiff`. ℹ `RankDiff = -...`. ℹ NAs introduced by coercion

Though I can see, a column `RankDiff` is formed with all `NAs`

I then changed the code to:

```
mutate(RankDiff = paste0("Rank",suffix1) - paste0("Rank",suffix2))
```

This gives the following error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `RankDiff`. ℹ `RankDiff = paste0("Rank", suffix1) - paste0("Rank", suffix2)`. x non-numeric
> argument to binary operator

What is the right way to pickup the columns by substitution?

Thanks.

Comment: In `mutate` `paste0("Rank",suffix1)` is not treated as a column name but simply as string. To access the column wrap the string inside e.g. the `.data` pronoun, i.e. `.data[paste0("Rank",suffix1)]`. For more on this see `?\`tidyeval-data\``

Comment: x `[` is not supported by .data pronoun, use `[[` or $ instead. Hence, I did ```.data[[paste0("Rank",suffix1)]]```

Comment: Sorry. I sometimes forget about that when just adding via a comment and not doing it myself in the console. (;

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `get`

```
library(dplyr) 

mergeddf <- left_join(df1, df2, by="col1", suffix = c(suffix1,suffix2)) %>% 
  select(-paste0("Description",suffix2)) %>% 
  mutate(RankDiff = get(paste0("Rank",suffix1)) - get(paste0("Rank",suffix2))) %>% 
  arrange(RankDiff)
```

Or with `sym` and `!!` -

```
mergeddf <- left_join(df1, df2, by="col1", suffix = c(suffix1,suffix2)) %>% 
  select(-paste0("Description",suffix2)) %>% 
  mutate(RankDiff = !!sym(paste0("Rank",suffix1)) - !!sym(paste0("Rank",suffix2))) %>% 
  arrange(RankDiff)
```